# android how to force cpu core offline(shut down cores)

Tags: android, adb, cpu, frequency, power-management

I'm using a **quad-core** smartphone.

I want to know how to force three cores or two cores **offline**. Thus I can measure the performance of different active core counts at different frequency level running a specified benchmark.

I can manage the core frequency through "*userspace governor*". However, I can't shut down cores. When I run benchmarks, the idle cores will wake up.

I've connect to the phone using "*adb shell*". I can get the root access either.

Could anyone help to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. You can set the cores to very low frequency, but I think shutting them "off" would be a security concern.

Answer (score 6):

run following commands to turn off cpu1, cpu2, cpu3.

```
adb root
adb shell stop mpdecision
adb shell
echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/online
echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/online
echo "0" > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online
```

Comment: These commands do not work all the time. Right after writing 0 into online, it becomes 1 again.

Comment: if mpdecision is still running , i can imagine this happening.

Comment: “mpdecision” is a cpu schedule mechanism for Qualcomm only.

Answer (score 1):

I had to disable **hotplug** first for the Galaxy-S7 device to prevent CPUs to **return to online** state:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuhotplug/enabled
```

On my device each write access to this file cause CPU state reset. So, **check existing value first** to not run into troubles:

```
if [[ 0 != $(cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuhotplug/enabled) ]]; then
    echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuhotplug/enabled
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force "online" status by changing permissions for the corresponding file:

```
# Without stopping this service, the following approach will fail
# You can run it after. This will increase battery life. So, I suggest to run it.
stop mpdecision

# Make the file writable
chmod 664 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online

# Make the core always offline
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online

# Make the file read-only. 
# Now "online" status will not be changed by external apps
chmod 444 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online

# Run the service again
start mpdecision
```

You have to run all that stuff for every cpu core.
I'd suggest to create a bash script, like that:

```
...
set_core_offline () {
    local core=$1
    chmod 664 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$core/online
    echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$core/online
    chmod 444 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu$core/online
}

# Works for 4-core CPUs
set_cores_offline () {
    set_core_offline 0
    set_core_offline 1
    set_core_offline 2
    set_core_offline 3
}
...
```

And, of course, this solution is not perfect. Look again, at the code snippet:

```
echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online
chmod 444 /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online
```

These are two separate commands. After execution of the first one, an external app might change "online" status to "1" again. After that the second command will fix this status as unchangeable. So, the clearest solution would be to wrap these 2 commands into a loop and check the status until we'd get desired results.